# Using Bootstrap 3 Carousel to change background image, any ideas for smooth fade transition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, transition

How can I make the changes to made to the `background-image` property in the following script transition a fade smoothly?

```
function carousel_background() {

    // gets bootstrap 3 carousel first/active image on load.
    $(window).load(function() {
        var load_img = 'url(' + $('.active img').attr("src") + ')';

        console.log(load_img);
        $('#background-img').css('background-image', load_img);

    });

      // gets carousel next active image
    $("#carousel-example-generic").on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {

        var active_img = 'url(' + $('.active img').attr("src") + ')';
        console.log(active_img);
        $('#background-img').css('background-image', active_img);
    });
}
```

also changing .on(slid.bs.carousel to .on(slide.bs.carousel  makes the timing of the picture change more in sync but then i change this "active_img" becomes the previous image.

---

im trying to achieve some thing similar to this website https://pro.beatport.com/

heres my attempt so far 
http://jsfiddle.net/milkysbeta/1vt1pLrs/5/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the css [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition) property. Note that at the time of this writing, support for the transition property on older browsers is a bit lacking but can be supplemented with the appropriate vendor prefixes.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2hqppttf/2/))

```
.active img {
    transition: background-image 1s linear;
}
```

Comment: Hmm I did try this but failed to mention why I did not use it , the reason is the size of images are all different so the .css linear tradition has a height adjust and looks terrible.

Comment: Take a look at my demo, using `background-size: cover` and two different sized images, there is no height adjustment.

Comment: This is the best answer to this question. :\

Answer (score 0):

Try stacking them on top of each other instead of down the page. Then using javascript change the images z-index of each image. Then just set a css transition on all the images.

Comment: yes i think you right but I am not to sure where to start with the javascript to do this kind of thing, any one care to give me a hit at what the code might look like... you can add this this http://jsfiddle.net/milkysbeta/1vt1pLrs/5/

Comment: It looks like your fiddle is doing what you wanted it to do, isn't it? If not what else did you want it to do?

Comment: the image is stretching during the transition and that also slows down the browser,

Comment: Well, I got it to work with jquery by kinda highjacking bootstraps calls and removing the css transition.
http://jsfiddle.net/t4jmzmr2/
It looks a little nicer but the performance still isn't great. I'm not a bootstrap guru it's possible there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: Cheers Tofu al also ended up cracking it today too thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sus is out with a fade out on "slide" and fade in on "slid"
https://jsfiddle.net/tnxtd2ho/ if you want to have a look

all though synchronization is still about a second to slow.

```
      // get carousel "slide" active image
$("#carousel-example-generic").on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {

    var active_img = 'url(' + $('.active img').attr("src") + ')';
    // fades out active image
    $('#background-img').css('background-image', active_img).animate({ opacity: 0 }, { duration: 1000 });
});


  // get carousel "slid" active image
$("#carousel-example-generic").on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {

    var active_img = 'url(' + $('.active img').attr("src") + ')';
    // fades in "slid" active image
    $('#background-img').css('background-image', active_img).animate({ opacity: 0.3 }, { duration: 300 });
});
```